# Regex to match all characters wrapped in a div tag

Tags: c#, html, regex

```
<div class="myClass">
<form method = "post" name="loginForm" >
<input type="text" name="userName"/>
</form>
<form method = "post" name="signupForm" >
<input type="text" name="userName"/>
</form>
</div>
```

if this was to be an example html.

```
<div>(.*?)</div>
```

So, something like this, anything (even nested tags) between opening and closing div tag

Comment: Please don't parse HTML with regex. Use a DOM parser (depends on the language you have). See what happens to those who do: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/871050

Comment: Use Html Agility Pack http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ to parse HTML, not regex!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps help you :

```
(<[div]+\s[a-zA-Z]+\=\"[a-zA-Z]+\">)(.*)(<\/[div]+>)
```

[image]

URL : https://www.regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this a few years ago, but with additional flexibility (capturing content of no matter what element):

```
<(?<element>\w+).*?>(?<content>.*)?</[\s]*\1>
```

Which works quite okay, but I have to agree with the comments above; if you can, use a fully fledged DOM parser! It'll handle edge cases etc...

Not if you really just want to get content of `<div />`'s that would be:

```
<(div).*?>(?<content>.*)?</[\s]*\1>
```