# Trouble with regex in Google App Script getting a lot of garbage after the result

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets, custom-function

Using this Google App Script to get cryptocurrency prices from coinmarketcap:
( credit for this script goes to Josh Bradley via this stackoverflow topic: [To exceed the ImportXML limit on Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39014766/to-exceed-the-importxml-limit-on-google-spreadsheet/48483734#48483734) )

```
function importRegex(url, regexInput) {
  var output = '';
  var fetchedUrl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  if (fetchedUrl) {
    var html = fetchedUrl.getContentText();
    if (html.length && regexInput.length) {
      output = html.match(new RegExp(regexInput, 'i'))[1];
    }
  }
  // Grace period to not overload
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  return output;
}
```

in the cell that I want to paste the price, I use:

```
=importRegex("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/cosmos", "<div class=.priceValue___11gHJ.>(.*)<\/div>")
```

But instead of the price, I get the price plus a lot of junk at the end.

```
$14.18</div><span ... (lots of stuff after)
```

Why isn't the regex working?  Thank you!

Comment: Regular expressions tend to be things that you have to test and they are often sensitive to minor variations in data.

Comment: So maybe instead of `.*` try `([$\\d.]{1,})` and possibly those double backslashes should just be one. I don't recall precisely.  Or this might work as well `([^<]{1,})` Here's a [reference](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)

Comment: Hi cooper that worked !  ([$\\d.]{1,}) and ([^<]{1,}) both worked / thank you so much!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11306596/1595451, https://stackoverflow.com/q/27939085/1595451

Comment: Can someone tell me how to get rid of the dollar sign in Cooper's answer?  it works and returns $13.99 for example, but I really need just 13.99.  this works but with the dollar sign ---> importRegex("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/cosmos", "<div class=.priceValue___11gHJ.>([^<]{1,})<\/div>"

Comment: Try `\$([\\d.]{1,})` I think the first backslash will let the expression know that you don't want the $ to be begining of line.  And you could always look for $ and remove it with a slice() method

Comment: @Cooper, thank you!, it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `.*` with `\$([\\d.]{1,})`.